# How to update an array's element in React?

Tags: reactjs

I need to update one of the properties of an element inside an array using [React's immutability helpers](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html).

I have something like this:

```js
this.setState(React.addons.update(this.state.collection[index], {
  property: { $set: !this.state.collection[index].property }
}));
```

Where `index` actually is the element's index on the collection, and `property` is a boolean which I'm trying to toggle.

The problem is the code isn't modifying the element's `property`, but a `property` property in the `this.state` object - so it gets to be something like `{collection: [...], property: true}`.

On [Nested Collections](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html#nested-collections) it says I should use a hash with the element's index as a key, but I have it in a variable, so it gets a bit ambiguous:

```js
this.setState(React.addons.update(this.state, {
  collection: {
    index: {
      property: { $set: !this.state.collection[index].property }
    }
  }
}));
```

It actually gives me a `Cannot read property 'property' of undefined` error - ie, `this.state.collection` doesn't have an `index` property, which is true.

**How can I achieve this?**

I already know I should use `$apply` instead of `$update` - but that's not the point here :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use dynamic properties to use the value of the variable `index` as property name:

```
this.setState(React.addons.update(this.state, {
  collection: {
    [index]: { // <--
      property: { $set: !this.state.collection[index].property }
    }
  }
}));
```

This is new in ES2015.